# WordPress Bulk category add to all posts with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, bulk

I have to add all of my old posts to new created category and keeping the categories posts are in. I've tried doing it via wordpress edit button, but it only does on 20 posts per page, and there are more than 100 pages. So I was wondering if there's a MySQL snippet I could execute and add the category to the posts at once???

Comment: Click on **Screen Option** and type number of posts you want to see at a time in the textbox and than apply.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is the code

```
<?php
$args = array( 'numberposts' => -1, 'orderby' => 'post_date' );
$postslist = get_posts( $args );
foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post);
$post_id = get_the_ID();

$cat_id = 99;
if ( !(in_category($cat_id)) ) {
    wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, array( $cat_id), 'category', false);
    echo 'No';
}else{

}
endforeach;
?>
```

The code is running a loop on all posts and pages and checking if category ID is not added into the post or page. if not added than add the category ID to the post or page.

Comment: thanks, but I have a :noob: question. where should I put it?!

Comment: Anywhere, I tested this in index.php
**DON'T FORGET TO THE CODE REMOVE AFTER CATEGORY IS ADDED TO THE POSTS**

Comment: damn, son. the script removed all the categories the posts where in and put them only in the new category. -.-" that wasn't cool at all.

Comment: @UnKnown, you've not taken into account the last parameter of `wp_set_object_terms()` `$append`. It defaults to `false` which means the code you gave him will replace all other categories associated with each post with the assigned category.

You may want to brush up on how this works: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms

Comment: Thanks Spencer, I modified the script.